# installing ros package without apt-get update?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install only a single package from ROS onto my Ubuntu 16.04 ARM. However, I don't want to update the list of packages from any repository. So when I skip the apt-get update step and directly jump to apt install package, I am unable to install the package ( Error: unable to locate ros-kinetic- ). Is there a workaround for this where I can skip updating the package list but only install the ros packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255362/installing-ros-package-without-apt-get-update?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a workaround for this where I can skip updating the package list but only install the ros packages?

If you want to use a package manager: *no*. The package manager needs to know which packages exist, and for that it needs to load something called an *index file*. And those files are exactly what gets downloaded when you run `apt-get update`.

Furthermore:

> I want to install only a single package from ROS onto my Ubuntu 16.04 ARM.

While this may seem like a simple thing, consider the fact that *all* ROS packages (and in fact: all software *ever* created) have runtime dependencies. Even if you say: "but I don't link to any libraries!", you'd still be using the C++ standard runtime library. For ROS nodes specifically, they'll always at least depend on a *client library* like `roscpp` or perhaps the Python libraries, but typically they'll depend on many more libraries (OpenCV, PCL, TF, msg packages, actionlib, etc, etc).

So even though you could relatively easily download a single `.deb`, extract it and then access the one binary that you're interested in, chances are that it'll be impossible to *run* it, as none of its dependencies are present on your "Ubuntu 16.04 ARM".

---

So is this completely impossible: no. If you're willing to build from sources and to figure out the exact dependencies of a particular package/node it can be done. It'll just be more work than "install only a single package" using the package manager. Perhaps you can check the [bmwcarit/meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) project (which actually builds *everything* from sources for embedded platforms) and see whether they have something that can do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-23**:
Thank you for the response ! The purpose of installing a single package was to just check if the Ubuntu I'm working on runs pre-built binaries of ROS properly without actually installing the entire ROS.

**Comment by [msadowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/19897/msadowski/) on 2017-02-23**:
You are right with building from source. If I had similar problem to OP I would definitely consider this solution.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-23**:
And initially, I thought I would check with turtlesim alone, since it has got a simple implementation,but then I realized that it first needs roscore to run which is in roslaunch package.So, I just installed roslaunch & ran roscore & rosgraph and they seem to be running pretty fine without any error

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-23**:
and coming to the apt-get update, I manually added the content of ros-latest.list to softwares and updates and it prompted a reload and doing so seems to have updated the cache with the list of ROS packages. Is this same as doing apt-get update?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
`apt-get update` is indeed the same as what a "reload" does in the *software* applet.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
re: minimal ROS installation: apart from selecting single packages, the `ros-$distro-ros-core` metapackage results in the smallest 'complete' ROS installation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-23**:
Finally: @sam26: this seems like a text-book example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). You ask: how do I install a single pkg / avoid `apt-get update`. You really want to know:

> check if the Ubuntu [..] runs pre-built binaries of ROS properly

It would be good to avoid this in the future.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-23**:
right!! Thank you for that clarification.